# NullPointerException using Spring Boot JPA when trying to save to database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, nullpointerexception

I am planning to play around with some trading data, and made a request to retrieve some markets data that I wish to store in mysql.

Since yesterday I have been stuck on a `NullPointerException` in my code. On StackOverflow I often see the error to be of trying to instantiate the Service for example, or forgotten annotations.

For me it seems to be going wrong whenever I try to use the Autowired Service. I invoke the method (that makes the data request in the Controller) from the main method for now. This does mean I have to instantiate in order to get there. This is probably where it goes wrong. I might be missing the concept of how to deal with this properly or how to save my data to the DAO. Hope someone can steer me in the right direction.

See the code below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DesktopAutoTradingApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        SpringApplication.run(DesktopAutoTradingApplication.class, args);
        MarketsBinanceController marketsBinanceController = new MarketsBinanceController();
        marketsBinanceController.saveListOfMarketsBinance();
    }
```

```java
@Controller
public class MarketsBinanceController{

    @Autowired
    RequestServices requestService;

    public void saveListOfMarketsBinance() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String resourceURL;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ResponseEntity<String> response;
        MarketsBinance marketsBinance;

        resourceURL = "https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/binance";
        response = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceURL, String.class);
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
        JsonNode result = root.get("result");
        System.out.println(result);
        List<MarketsBinance> markets = new ArrayList<>();
        for(JsonNode item : result){
            marketsBinance = new MarketsBinance();
            MarketsBinanceDto marketsBinanceDto;
            marketsBinanceDto = mapper.treeToValue(item,MarketsBinanceDto.class);
            marketsBinance.setId(marketsBinanceDto.getId());
            marketsBinance.setExchange(marketsBinanceDto.getExchange());
            marketsBinance.setPair(marketsBinanceDto.getPair());
            marketsBinance.setActive(marketsBinanceDto.getActive());
            marketsBinance.setRoute(marketsBinanceDto.getRoute());
            markets.add(marketsBinance);
            requestService.saveMarketsBinance(markets);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class RequestServices {

    @Autowired
    private MarketsBinanceDAO marketsBinanceDAO;

    public void saveMarketsBinance(List<MarketsBinance> markets){
        marketsBinanceDAO.saveAll(markets);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public interface MarketsBinanceDAO extends CrudRepository<MarketsBinance, Long> {

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class MarketsBinance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long tableId;
    private Long id;
    private String exchange;
    private String pair;
    private Boolean active;
    private String route;

//getters and setters
```

```java
public class MarketsBinanceDto {

    private Long id;
    private String exchange;
    private String pair;
    private Boolean active;
    private String route;

//getters and setters
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Controller.MarketsBinanceController.saveListOfMarketsBinance(MarketsBinanceController.java:46)
    at com.DAT.DesktopAutoTrading.DesktopAutoTradingApplication.main(DesktopAutoTradingApplication.java:16)
```

Below you find the error message received upon running the program adding the proposed solution in the first answer.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Controller.MarketsBinanceController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1127)
    at com.DAT.DesktopAutoTrading.DesktopAutoTradingApplication.main(DesktopAutoTradingApplication.java:15)
2020-09-07 12:24:03.545  INFO 22756 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-07 12:24:03.553  INFO 22756 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Can you add the exception you're getting with stack trace?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question exactly (pasting the actual exception would definitely help), but as far as I recall, going through a `main` method sidesteps some of the internal wiring that Spring does.

Comment: @npinti Good point. Doing `MarketsBinanceController marketsBinanceController = new MarketsBinanceController();` in the main method would not inject `marketsBinanceDAO` so `marketsBinanceDAO.saveAll()` will throw a NullPointer because `marketsBinanceDAO` is null.

Comment: Difficult to say without the exception, but one thing I can say for sure is that `requestService`, does not seem to be getting updated to an actual instance.

Comment: @phonaputer how would I execute the function in the controller when I cannot instantiate it- I already mentioned that this is likely the problem, but cannot think of how to go?

Comment: I have added the error message to the original message. + the error message after implementing the proposed solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use bean of type `MarketsBinanceController` that Spring created and configured instead of `MarketsBinanceController marketsBinanceController = new MarketsBinanceController();`.

To get this bean in main method you should get `ApplicationContext`. `ApplicationContext` you can get as returned object from `SpringApplication.run(DesktopAutoTradingApplication.class, args);`.

Complete code example:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DesktopAutoTradingApplication.class, args);
MarketsBinanceController marketsBinanceController = context.getBean(MarketsBinanceController.class);
marketsBinanceController.saveListOfMarketsBinance();
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this results in the following error:Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Controller.MarketsBinanceController' available
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:352) ......etc

Comment: Would I need to add some annotation to the MarketsBinanceController class?

Comment: Spring boot automatically scans package which contains your main class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and all it's sub-packages. If your `MarketsBinanceController` annotated as `@Controller` make sure that it located in scannable sub-package

Comment: @AlmostGr In stack traces you posted I see that your main class `DesktopAutoTrading` located in `com.DAT` package and `MarketsBinanceController` in `Controller` package. If you will move `MarketsBinanceController` in `com.DAT.Controller` package it should be working

Comment: @AlmostGr or you can modify your `@SpringBootApplication` to `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = MarketsBinanceController .class)`. Then Spring will additionaly scan package which contains `MarketsBinanceController`

Comment: Thanks so much, I indeed missed the fact that my packages were not all under the package from the DesktopAutoTradingApplication. I thought I did, and I guess this is a great example of assumption being the mother of.... Thanks once more!